# Sort array using two thirds algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I came across an uncommon sorting algorithm.
The algorithm sorts the first 2/3rd of an array then next 2/3rd of an array and again sorts the first 2/3rd of an array recursively.

```
fun sort3(a: int list): int list =
  case a of
    nil => nil
  | [x] => [x]
  | [x,y] => [Int.min(x,y), Int.max(x,y)]
  | a => let
      val n = List.length(a)
      val m = (2*n+2) div 3
      val res1 = sort3(List.take(a, m))
      val res2 = sort3(List.drop(res1, n-m) @
                       List.drop(a, m))
      val res3 = sort3(List.take(res1, n-m) @
                       List.take(res2, 2*m-n))
    in
      res3 @ List.drop(res2,2*m-n)
    end
```

The recursive relation for this algorithm is written as

```
T(n) = 2T(n/3) + O(n)
```

I dint understand how this algo works.

What I understand is, 
1.It recursively calls the same function until the array size is 3 then sort the array using bruteforce.
2. then merge the arrays (like in merge sort) using o(n) time.

Am I right?

I dont understand the language it is written in, So I could not understand the code.Can anyone help me understanding this algorithm.

PS: This is not homework.

Comment: Looks like OCaml (or some kind of ML anyway).

Comment: See Problem 2 [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~eugene/teach/algs00a/works/s3.pdf) for a description of the algorithm in pseudocode and a proof of correctness.